# Android app network traffic capture not working

Tags: android, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've two apps. When I add proxy from wifi settings to capture the traffic using burp suite, one app works properly but another one doesn't.

Using MeMu Emulator (Rooted)

BURP Certificate is installed at root level

Update : the app was having certificate in it, I replaced it with the burp  certificate. The app is working now but the request body is encrypted, and response is json which is not encrypted.

How can I get the decrypted request body?